# Why does the the R package igraph say that these two graphs aren't isomorphic?

Tags: r, igraph, isomorphic

The code below uses the igraph package of R to generate two graphs, G1 and G2, which should be isomorphic. The first check claims they are not, but the second says they are. The only difference is that I replaced the 6's in the first e1 with 4's in the second e1.

```
library(igraph)
e1 = c(1,2,1,5,2,1,2,5,2,6,3,5,5,1,5,2,5,3,5,6,6,2,6,5)
e2 = c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,2,1,2,5,3,1,3,5,4,1,5,1,5,2,5,3)
G1 = make_graph(e1)
G2 = make_graph(e2)
isomorphic(G1,G2)

e1 = c(1,2,1,5,2,1,2,5,2,4,3,5,5,1,5,2,5,3,5,4,4,2,4,5)
G1 = make_graph(e1)
isomorphic(G1,G2)
```

When I drew out the first two graphs it was clear to me that they were in fact isomorphic, as you can see in the image below.

[image: Two isomorphic graphs]

Why does the function isomorphic of the R package igraph give an incorrect result? Is it known that in some cases it doesn't work?

Comment: in your first example if you plot the graph G2, there is only 5 nodes, but six in the first, G1 - so not isomorphic

Comment: Ooooh, so in G1 it adds node 4 even though I didn't specify it. Thanks that was all I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've been tripped up by the difference in the handling of numeric and character vectors by `igraph::make_graph`:

```
library(igraph)
e1 = as.character(c(1,2,1,5,2,1,2,5,2,6,3,5,5,1,5,2,5,3,5,6,6,2,6,5))
e2 = as.character(c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,2,1,2,5,3,1,3,5,4,1,5,1,5,2,5,3))
G1 = make_graph(e1)
G2 = make_graph(e2)
isomorphic(G1,G2)
plot(G1); plot(G2)
#[1] TRUE
```

The "isolates" parameter is ignored in numeric arguments to `make_graph`, and it appears that numeric arguments cause a presumption that all values in the range of values are to be included.